# What is the difference between @action and @api_view to create routes in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-rest-viewsets

Both decorators appear to simply create a route for you. But what would be the practical difference (if any)? In the documentation, it is not clear.

I even created two routes the same way and there was no difference

Answer (score 1):

@action is used to make methods in existing ViewSets [routable](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing):

> If you have ad-hoc methods that should be routable, you can mark them
> as such with the @action decorator.

@api_view "converts" normal function based view functions to DRF views. The [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#function-based-views) explain it best:

> REST framework also allows you to work with regular function based
> views. It provides a set of simple decorators that wrap your function
> based views to ensure they receive an instance of Request (rather than
> the usual Django HttpRequest) and allows them to return a Response
> (instead of a Django HttpResponse), and allow you to configure how the
> request is processed.
> The core of this functionality is the api_view decorator, which takes
> a list of HTTP methods that your view should respond to.

Comment: So basically both create views with no difference. Right?